# Combobox with Textbox content issue

Tags: c#, wpf

I am running into an issue when using a textbox as the content of a combobox in WPF. When I have some items in the combobox already and then enter an extension of one of those items in the textbox, the textbox clears itself when it matches one of the existing items. An example:

The combobox contains the following:

- 'test1'
- 'test2'

I then attempt to enter the value 'test23'. When I get to 'test2' the matching value in the combobox is highlighted. When I proceed to type the '3' in 'test23', the textbox is cleared and all I am left with is a '3'. Obviously this is not a desired behavior.

I've looked through the configurable properties on microsoft's documentation pages and I haven't been able to find a property or combination that allows me to disable this behavior. Does anyone know what's going on here as well how I might fix it? Thanks.

Comment: Please post the code, that exhibits this behavior. I guess it should be only XAML, but if there is C# code involved, please post that too. that will help answering your question

Answer (score 0):

If your are trying to add extension text to your default text in combobox items, try in code behind to declare the text items as a stringbuilder and use the property Append as follow

Code behind:

```
    System.Text.StringBuilder text = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
    TextBox textitem = new TextBox();
    text="set the default text you want";
    textitem.text=text;
    Combobox.items.add(textitem);
    text.append("the extension text you want");
```

Hope it helps.